# Compiling different scetions for different version - Java

Tags: blackberry, java-compiler-api

Is there any way to compile BlackBerry Java code for different sections using eclipse ?
There is a class named **LocationInfo**  available in BB version OS 6.0 onwards.

I get a compilation error if try to compile for OS 5 (because LocationInfo is 
not defined)
But if I compile my code for OS 6, I wont be able to deploy on any 5 based devices.

I want to my code base to be of version 5 and support the methods of **Locationinfo**  (which is available only in 6.0 onwards).
Is a sectional compile possible or is there any work around for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [BlackBerry preprocessor](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1407892/How_To_-_Use_the_preprocessor.html?nodeid=1487658&vernum=0)

Comment: one downside to the preprocessor is that it is very bare-bones. For instance, it does not support nested or compound `#ifdef` statements. I have encountered several occasions when having those would have made my preprocessed code easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

[Coding for Multiple Blackberry Devices - Using Preprocessor Directives in Eclipse](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/coding-for-multiple-blackberry-devices.html)

Answer (score 0):

The OP wanted to know whether there was a way to a class available in os 6.0  , in an os 5.0 device. The blackberry processor does help in creating builds for different versions, but doesnt answer the question. The OP would like to know whether there is the blackberry equivalent to androids "Support Package" or the "Compatibility package" which allows to  use APIs that are not available for older platform versions.

Sorry , but there is no similar package on blackberry which you can use to address your issue.

You will have to use blackberry pre processor and then develop features for different devices based on the os they provide. Later OS's will have more apis you can play with, so you can implement better features on those. In earlier OS's you are stuck with using the restricted set of api methods, and hence some features may not be implemented on those.

Hope this helps